# MiddleStorm middleware with bottle

Tags: python, wsgi, bottle

How do you use [MiddleStorm](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/middlestorm) middleware with [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/)?
I followed [this example](http://readthedocs.org/docs/bottle/en/latest/recipes.html), replacing SessionMiddleware with MiddleStorm, but I can't get it to work.

```
from bottle import *
from storm.locals import *
from middlestorm import MiddleStorm

#other bottle code like this here...
@get('/')
   def index():
   return 'index'

db = create_database("mysql://user:pass@localhost/mydb")
myapp = MiddleStorm(app, db)
run(app=myapp, reloader=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=4321)
```

I get this error in console:

```
exceptions.TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

If I change the line with myapp to:

```
myapp = MiddleStorm(app(), db)
```

I get this error on the webpage:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/bottle.py", line 651, in _handle
    return callback(**args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/bottle.py", line 1143, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
TypeError: decorator() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

edit: bottle, storm, middlestorm are installed

edit2: if I chane myapp line to myapp = MiddleStorm(dafault_app, db) I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/middlestorm-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/middlestorm.py", line 68, in __call__
    return self._app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
homer - - [17/Jul/2011 16:28:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

edit3: with @zeekay code I still get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/bottle.py", line 651, in _handle
    return callback(**args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/bottle.py", line 1143, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
TypeError: decorator() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually `default_app` and `app` are synonymous. This should work:

```
myapp = MiddleStorm(app(), db)
```

Just testing briefly and it seems to work for me. Can you try testing this:

```
from bottle import *
from storm.locals import *
from middlestorm import MiddleStorm

@get('/')
def index():
   return 'index'

db = create_database("sqlite://test.db")
myapp = MiddleStorm(app(), db)
run(app=myapp, reloader=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=4321)
```

You should be able to drop it in a file and just run.

Comment: To explain this answer a bit more, the middleware is expecting to wrap an actual wsgi app, but the request handlers in bottle aren't that, rather bottle uses those to construct a wsgi app.